# permanent url redirect in umbraco 7

Tags: redirect, umbraco7, permanent

I was having old url like 
    http://mydomain/blog/posts/2015/february/fill-and-follow/

and new url now is like
    http://mydomain/blog/posts/fill-and-follow/

So, for above scenario I want to write re-write rule. I am using rule as follows in UrlRewriting.config.

```
<add name="urlRedirect1"
 virtualUrl= "http://mydomain/blog/posts(.*)"
 rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
 destinationUrl="http://mydomain/blog/posts/$1/"
 ignoreCase="true"
 redirect="Application"
 redirectMode="Permanent" />
```

What will be the actual rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the above.

the correct answer is as below.

```
<add name="BlogRewrite"
virtualUrl="http://mydomain/blog/posts/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$"
rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
destinationUrl="http://mydomain/blog/posts/$3/"
redirect="Domain"
redirectMode="Permanent"
ignoreCase="true" />
```